# Windows phone 8.1 chat application using websocket with a Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, sockets, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to develop a chat application in windows phone 8.1(not universal or silverlight). I created a server with Node.JS and with socket.io.how i can connect to nodejs server from windows phone 8.1?. please anybody help me out with this.im looking for this for the last 3 weeks.thnks in advance

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226960.aspx

Comment: How i can connect to the nodejs server from windows phone 8.1 using Windows.Networking.Sockets

Comment: I have never worked with WP -> socket.io connection, but I suppose you could use any websocket library to connect to socket server. You instantiate a websocket, make a connection and then receive/send messages.

Comment: Im new to WP8.1 and im creating my first app, so i dont know  which library to use for the server connection.i googled a lot bt didnt get the right one..

Comment: After a quick google search I found this one: https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet. Although, I think you should first invest some time to get basic understanding of websockets in general, maybe it would then be easier for you.